# Dispatch an action from ApolloClient onError

Tags: redux, apollo-client

I am using Redux and Apollo Client in my project. I would like to dispatch an action to trigger a message bar on top, stating the session is expired, when GraphQL endpoint returns 401 (Session expired).

But the `client` object is not an component, I cannot use `useDispatch` here, is there any way I can dispatch an action in `onError`?

```
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-client";
import { onError } from "apollo-link-error";
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";

const customFetch = (uri, options) => {
    return fetch(uri, options)
    .then(response => {
        console.log("response fetch", response)
        switch (response.status) {
            case 400:
            case 401:
            case 500:
            case 504:
                return Promise.reject(response);
            default:
                return response;
        }   
    });
  };

const requestLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: "/graphql",
    fetch: customFetch,
});

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, response }) => {

    if (graphQLErrors)
        graphQLErrors.map(({ message, extensions }) => {
            console.log(`[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${extensions.code}`);
        });
    if (networkError) {
        // TODO: Dispatch error to trigger a message bar component appear
        console.log("[GraphQL networkError], ", networkError);
    }
});

const link = errorLink.concat(requestLink);

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: errorLink.concat(requestLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
        addTypename: false,
    }),
});

export default client;
```